# flutter web browser finder not finding special characters

Tags: flutter, find

In a flutter project, the browser finder can find normal text , for example "fu":

[image1 text found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfGzR.jpg)

But trying some characters ("-", "_", "." and other) are not found, example "fu__":

[image2 text NOT found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v44t.jpg)

Is there any way or plugin to fix it?

Comment: does it work if you search for "fu_se"?

Comment: Unfortunatelly "fu_se" does not work

Comment: can you provide your code, where these characters come, and are you using some different font style?

Comment: The code is:

Expanded(child: SelectableText("fu_se")),
Expanded(child: Text("fu_se")),

The chars come from a futurebuilder or plain text, both with the same problem.

Basic fontstyle.

It happens on all the Flutter project: Appbar, ListView, Datatable ...